# C# Regex to replace specific hashtags with certain block of text

Tags: c#

I am a new C# developer and I am struggling right now to write a method to replace a few specific hashtags in a sample of tweets with certain block of texts. For example if the tweet has a hashtag like #StPaulSchool, I want to replace this hashtag with this certain text "St. Paul School" without the '#' tag. 
I have a very small list of the certain words which I need to replace. If there is no match, then I would like remove the hashtag (replace it with empty string)

I am using the following method to parse the tweet and convert it into a formatted tweet but I don't know how to enhance it in order to handle the specific hashtags. **Could you please tell me how to do that?**

Here's the code:

```
public string ParseTweet(string rawTweet)
        {
            Regex link = new Regex(@"http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?");
            Regex screenName = new Regex(@"@\w+");
            Regex hashTag = new Regex(@"#\w+");

            var words_to_replace = new string[] { "StPaulSchool", "AzharSchool", "WarwiSchool", "ManMet_School", "BrumSchool"};
            var inputWords = new string[] { "St. Paul School", "Azhar School", "Warwick School", "Man Metapolian School", "Brummie School"};

            string formattedTweet = link.Replace(rawTweet, delegate (Match m)
            {
                string val = m.Value;
                //return string.Format("URL");
                return string.Empty;
            });

            formattedTweet = screenName.Replace(formattedTweet, delegate (Match m)
            {
                string val = m.Value.Trim('@');
                //return string.Format("USERNAME");
                return string.Empty;
            });

            formattedTweet = hashTag.Replace(formattedTweet, delegate (Match m)
            {
                string val = m.Value;
                //return string.Format("HASHTAG");
                return string.Empty;
            });

            return formattedTweet;
        }
```

Comment: You should use the `Uri` class to parse a URI, not regex.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using regular expressions makes this code unreadable and difficult to maintain. Moreover, you are using regular expression to find a very simple pattern - to find strings that starts with the hashtag (#) character.

I suggest a different approach: Break the sentence into words, transform each word according to your business rules, then join the words back together. Although this sounds like a lot of work, and it may be the case in another language, the C# String class makes this quite easy to implement.

Here is a basic example of a console application that does the requested functionality, the business rules are hard-coded, but this should be enough so you could continue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Example #First #Second #NoMatch not a word ! \nSecond row #Second";
    string[] wordsInText = text.Split(' ');
    IEnumerable<string> transformedWords = wordsInText.Select(selector: word => ReplaceHashTag(word: word));
    string transformedText = string.Join(separator: " ", values: transformedWords);
    Console.WriteLine(value: transformedText);
}

private static string ReplaceHashTag(string word)
{
    if (!word.StartsWith(value: "#"))
    {
        return word;
    }
    string wordWithoutHashTag = word.Substring(startIndex: 1);

    if (wordWithoutHashTag == "First")
    {
        return "FirstTransformed";
    }
    if (wordWithoutHashTag == "Second")
    {
        return "SecondTransformed";
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Note that this approach gives you much more flexibility chaining your logic, and by making small modifications you can make this code a lot more testable and incremental then the regular expression approach

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for the hashtags:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string longTweet = @"Long sentence #With #Some schools like #AzharSchool and spread out
over two #StPaulSchool lines ";

        string result = Regex.Replace(longTweet, @"\#\w+", match => ReplaceHashTag(match.Value), RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static string ReplaceHashTag(string input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "#StPaulSchool": return "St. Paul School";
            case "#AzharSchool": return "Azhar School";
            default:
                return input; // hashtag not recognized
        }
    }
```

If the list of hashtags to convert becomes very long it would be more succint to use a Dictionary, eg:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _hashtags
        = new Dictionary<string, string>
              {
                  { "#StPaulSchool", "St. Paul School" },
                  { "#AzharSchool", "Azhar School" },
              };
```

and rewrite the body of the `ReplaceHashTag` method with this:

```
        if (!_hashtags.ContainsKey(hashtag))
        {
            return hashtag;
        }

        return _hashtags[hashtag];
```

Comment: thanks for your help in this regard. I like your approach with the Dictionary. However I got confused in how to incorporate the Dictionary with the `ReplaceHashTag` method as there is no relation between both of them and there is no relation between them and the `Main` method. Could you please explain it more to me?

Comment: The example I gave you was written in a Console app. Since its `Main` method is static, I made the `ReplaceHashTag` also static. The dictionary was declared as a **static** field.